# Capybara have_selector is not working on checkbox

Tags: rspec, capybara

On my view I have a checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" id="modal-checkbox" class="painter-modal-checkbox" data-reactid=".1.1:1.0.0">
```

On my capybara code, I am trying to use the have_selector method

```
expect(page).to have_selector("#modal-checkbox")
```

This fails, when I am tracing the page with

```
print page.html
```

I can confirm that my html code is there, why does this test fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually because the field isn't actually visible because it's hidden via CSS. With checkboxes this is often because the design calls for the label to be used to show the selected state of the checkbox while the actual checkbox is hidden.  To check if visibility is the issue you can pass visible: false to have_selector, however 99% of the time you shouldn't be checking for invisible items since a user wouldn't be able to see them or interact with them

Comment: So what should be used to check for hidden tags then? I ran into this problem with <input type="hidden"> form fields I want to check in my view tests (not integration or feature tests — but view tests where I need to make sure I’m generating the right fields, visible or not).

Comment: Ah, moments later I found the answer: add the “visible: false” parameter to the have_selector call. E.g.:
expect(rendered).to have_selector('input[type="hidden"]', visible: false)

Comment: @GrantNeufeld Correct - as mentioned in the answer - however checking for the presence of non-visible elements really is a bad code smell in tests.  What difference does it make to a user if they are not-visible or just not in the page code? You should be testing the behavior that makes them visible or depends on them being hidden on the page rather than testing the presence of a hidden element.

Comment: Except that some invisible elements do have an impact on the user:
• The hidden `input[name="_method"]` determines the action Rails will perform when a user interacts with a form.
• Some hidden metadata will be processed by non-human users (such as when embedding microformats).
• Some hidden elements may be used by assistive devices for people with disabilities.

Comment: @GrantNeufeld the hidden `input[name="_method"]` should be tested, in a feature test, by submitting the form and making sure the app does the correct thing, not checking for the presence of a hidden input field. For  microformats and assistive tags, if you can't test the desired results in browser then they are more suited for testing in view specs rather than feature specs.

Comment: I am doing this testing in view specs. (I also do feature tests, but there I don’t care about the semantic specifics of the html generated, but the behaviours that result.). I could go back to the uglier old assert syntax that doesn’t care about visibility (and I assume doesn’t share the Capybara code for parsing html), but the have_selector syntax seems to be the “common practice” in rspec now and I find it cleaner to write and read.